# How can I get the value of an Int in an differnet activity? getIntent() doesnt work anymore

Tags: java, android, android-studio, int

Hi I want to recieve my string data in another activity.
I found this code on youtube:

Activity 1:

```
public static final String FINISHED_LEVELS = "com.example.rexan_snerficonquiz.Quiz_Fragment.FINISHED_LEVELS";
public static final String SKIPPED_LEVELS = "com.example.rexan_snerficonquiz.Quiz_Fragment.SKIPPED_LEVELS";
public static final String FAILED_LEVELS = "com.example.rexan_snerficonquiz.Quiz_Fragment.FAILED_LEVELS";
public static final String USED_HINTS = "com.example.rexan_snerficonquiz.Quiz_Fragment.USED_HINTS";

public void openActifity2(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), Fragment_score.class);
    intent.putExtra(FINISHED_LEVELS, finishedLevels);
    intent.putExtra(FAILED_LEVELS, failedLevels);
    intent.putExtra(USED_HINTS, usedHints);
    intent.putExtra(SKIPPED_LEVELS, skippedLevels);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Activity 2:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int finishedLevels = intent.getIntExtra(Quiz_Fragment.FINISHED_LEVELS,0);
    int failedLevels = intent.getIntExtra(Quiz_Fragment.FAILED_LEVELS, 0);
    int skippedLevels = intent.getIntExtra(Quiz_Fragment.SKIPPED_LEVELS, 0);
    int usedHints = intent.getIntExtra(Quiz_Fragment.USED_HINTS, 0);
```

But getIntent() doesnt work anymore. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it may work

In activity1.java

```
   Intent intent=new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
   intent.putExtra(Key,Value);
   context.startActivity(intent);
```

get in Activity2.java

```
   int mValue=getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Key);
```